# Selenium page scrolling no longer works

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following problem: my page scrolling in Selenium stopped working, I was scrolling pages with the same code just yesterday, the next day I sat down at my computer and scrolling no longer works.

I do not understand what the problem, I guess I have to remove all the python, a browser and ChromeDriver reinstall, maybe then solve the problem, but before that I would like to know from you, maybe there is another solution?

The code, which exactly worked, is shown below, even if you can even just leave one single line:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

that scrolls, and there will still be no scrolling):

```
# Load the data until we reach the end date
while (True):
    search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "EventItem__item-2z3yK")

    last_date = get_date_from_string(search_results[-1:][0].text)

    if check_date_interval(last_date):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    else:
        break
```

To find out what the problem is:

- I created a separate project with nothing but scrolling;
- I tried different sites and different methods, (about 3) up to scrolling with "Send.Keys";
- I cleared the project of all libraries, and install them again, later versions;
  But none of it worked.

I expect the scrolling to finally start working, I don't understand why it worked two days before and stopped on the third.

Comment: do you want to scroll to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @soundwave Yes, to the bottom.

Comment: well then just run `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', search_results[-1])`

Comment: @soundwave your method really worked!
I really don't understand why the sing method stopped working, although it worked before for sure. And even through scrolling applications "Down Arrow" or "End" does not work for me.

Comment: @soundwave Thank you so much, I tried about 5 scrolling options and nothing worked, but your method worked, only I changed the behavior to auto to scroll faster. Well, why the banal scrolling by pressing the keys does not work remains a mystery.

Comment: @soundwave Could you post your answer as a full text instead of as a comment so I can mark the solution?

Comment: The subtle problem with scrolling is that a priori you never know where is the focus on the page (there might be a sidebar menu, popup or a generic webelement with scroll functionality), so keys or window.scrollTo or other methods may not work sometimes. While scrollIntoView works most of the time because you specify which element to scroll to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best and easiest way is to scroll to a specific element of the page, in this case the last search result

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "auto"});', search_results[-1])
```